# Narrow down specific members of this in a method

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I want to call a specific function inside a class, but only allow the call to that function, if a nullable property is currently set.

The code I have:

```
class VisualComponent {
  public fallback_color: p5.Color;
  public image: p5.Image | null = null;

  public constructor(color:p5.Color) {
    this.fallback_color = color;
  }

  public draw(p:p5) {
    if (this.image) {
      this.draw_image(p);
    } else {
      p.fill(this.fallback_color);
      p.rect(0,0,100,100);
    }
  }

  private draw_image(p:p5) {
      // this has potentially a bit more logic in it or
      // is different in subclasses
      p.drawImage(this.image);  // <-- Error this.image is possibly null
  }
}
```

I hope the code above gets the point across. I want to tell the 'draw_image' function, that it can only be called if this.image is currently set.

```
let visual = new VisualComponent(p.color(0,0,255));
visual.draw(); // <-- draws the color
visual.image = __some_image__;
visual.draw(); // <-- draws the image
```

So I assume I need some typeguards similar to here: [Keep track of state in class instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57475635/keep-track-of-state-in-class-instance/57564436#57564436)

```
type VisualComponentWithImage = VisualComponent & {image:p5.Image}; 

class VisualComponent {
  ...
  public has_image(): this is VisualComponentWithImage {
    if (this.image) return true;
    return false;
  }

  // well, now I can use the typeguard here but the 'draw_image' function
  // is still not narrowed down obviously
  public draw(p:p5) {
    if (this.has_image()) {
      this.draw_image(p);
    } else {
      p.fill(this.fallback_color);
      p.rect(0,0,100,100);
    }
  }

  // I expect now to do the following
  private draw_image(p:p5) : this if VisualComponentWithImage  {
    // and in here this should be of type VisualComponentWithImage  
    // as well as any call to this prior to asserting that image exists should be a type error
  }
  ...
}
```

I made some adventures in the Typescript Documentation:

https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html

I think the `ThisType<T>` might be something in the right direction, but I couldn't figure out how to use it in an already existing class context.
(it seems to be used for dynamically created classes in the example)

https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/decorators.html
Decorators look to me as if they could solve the problem.
But they honestly look a bit intimidating and not quite neat to use.
Neat is what I want after all.

My current solution is to have the 'draw_image' function to be separated from the class as follows:

```
function draw_image(this: VisualComponentWithAnimation, p:p5) {
    p.drawImage(p);
}
```

which I call like this inside the 'draw' function

```
if (this.has_image()) {
  draw_image(this, p);
}
```

Ideally though I would want to have that function inside the class, just to have it were it belongs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just during formulating the question a had the solving idea.
Or rather i tried something stupid, that turned out to be working.

I simply moved the
`draw_image(this: VisualComponentWithAnimation, p:p5) ...` 
inside the class and that was it.

I never thought i could 'override' `this` like that inside a class.
But it perfectly narrows down 'this' inside the function,
is called like any other class method `this.draw_image(p);`
(not explicitly putting in "this") and also disallows calls if 'image' is not set.

I gues sometimes writing an essay also helps solving an issue.